# Why can my perceptron not separate perfectly a number of points that are less than the number of features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, perceptron

I am quite new in machine learning and decided that a good way to start getting some experience would be to play around with some real data bases and the python scikit library. I used haberman's surgery data, a binary classification task, that can be found at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Haberman%27s+Survival. I trained a few perceptrons using this data. At some point, I decided to demonstrate the concept of overfitting. Therefore, I mapped all 306 data points, of 3 features each, to a very high dimension, getting all terms up to and including the 11th degree. That is a vast 364 features (which is more than the 306 data points). Yet, when I trained the model, I did not achieve zero in-sample error. I figured the reason should be that there are some points that coincide and have different labels, so I removed duplicate data points, but again, I could not achieve zero in-sample error. Here is the interesting part of my code using the methods of the scikit library:

```
perceptron = Perceptron()
polynomial = preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(11)
perceptron.fit(polynomial.fit_transform(X), Y)
print(perceptron.score(polynomial.fit_transform(X),Y))
```

And the output I got was a mere 0.7, an accuracy score far from 1 (100%) that I expected. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please provide the full code that you are using? Reading the data, eliminating the duplicates etc..

Answer (score 0):

You only have 11 polynomial features. If you want to be guaranteed to hit every point you need almost as many if not more polynomial features than your number of datapoints. This is because each additional polynomial feature allows the graph to bend again.

Having a bunch of features of the same degree can't really increase your complexity in the way you expect. If your function is first degree for example, you really can't expect it to be anything other than linear, regardless of the like term count.

So while you may have more features than datapoints, since you don't have more polynomial features than datapoints most of your features are effectively tweaking the same weights.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Even if you stay linear, a dataset with more features will allow to correctly classify more points compared to one with less. The VC dimension, which is the number of points that can be shuttered, equals the number of parameters (ie weights) not the order of the polynomial. So even though I am using an eleventh order polynomial, the number of weights is what matters, and that is 364. Nonetheless, I picked 50 random points (to have the algorithm converge quickly), applied a 50th order polynomial transform to it, and my in-sample accuracy was even less! Namely 0.67.

Comment: It is true that a dataset with more features usually be able to classify more of the training data correctly. But you still can't get anything other than linear without a nonlinear activation function or polynomial features. 

If you don't use an activation function then you're doing theta0 * bias + theta1 * x1 + theta2 * x2 + theta3 * x3 ... but (theta1 + theta2 + theta3) is just a scaler and (x1 + x2 + x3) is just another first degree polynomial. You're effectively just twisting the same knobs over and over again. It is possible that you might need to tweak other parameters however like lr

Comment: You can of course, get a higher training accuracy with more features depending on what degree polynomial is required to separate the data. A First degree polynomial is sufficient to separate linearly separable Data but is incapable of perfectly separating non-linearly separable data